# What are the formal names of the pieces of text input to a terminal to run something?

Tags: terminal, command, command-prompt

I'm trying to understand what the formal names are for the pieces of text that make up running something from the terminal/command line.  Take the following example:

`npm install lodash --save`

What are `npm`, `install`, `lodash`, and `--save` named if you were to break them down one by one?  Was thinking the below, but not sure and am curious to find out.  Also wondering what you would call the whole piece of text.

- npm = program?
- install = command?
- lodash = argument?
- --save = option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't really formal names due to the widely varying structure "applications"/"programs" and their arguments can be designed.

If you do `man man` for example, you'll see the reference manual for the `man` program which is used for describing other processes.  In this man page you'll see it using some common descriptive terms such as "process" and "arguments" but outside that the terms used are usually specific to the design of the process itself.

Just as an example you'll notice the reference to "program, utility, or function" in the first line of the description referring to the "command" being run:

> DESCRIPTION: 
>         man is the system's manual pager.  Each page argument given to man is normally the name of a program, utility or function.  The manual  page associated with each of these arguments is then found and displayed.  A section, if provided, will direct man to look only in that section of the manual.  The default action is to search in all of the available sections following a pre-defined order ("1 n l  8 3 2 3posix 3pm 3perl 3am 5 4 9 6 7" by default, unless overridden by the SECTION directive in /etc/manpath.config), and to show only the first page found, even if page exists in several sections.

Answer (score 0):

- npm is the program.
- install is the command.
- lodash is the package
- --save is the option.

Comment: Is there a generic term for "package" specific for the terminal?  `docker start <container name>`, what would `lodash` and `<container name>` be called?  Or would they just be package and container and is different depending on the program?